# Относительный импорт за пределами пакета верхнего уровня

Tags: python

Есть программа, разбитая на модули. На верхнем уровне помимо `main.py` находится файл `c_data.py` (грубо говоря конфиги, которые нельзя сделать через `.env`)

Так вот эту `c_dat'у` я импортирую в `.modules.Getter`, что естественно вызывает ошибку импорта.

Как мне эту ошибку исправить?
`sys.path.append(..)`, запуск через `-m` не помогают

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

p.s. при чем в других моих проектах ровно такая же ситуация ошибок не вызывала, в чем дело я так и не понял

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
# from main - каталог проекта
# import main - имя файла 

from main import main
```